# How to organize api requests right in Emberjs?

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js

Recently I met with EmberJS. There are a few questions, I can not find answers in the documentation.

1. Authorized user retrieves data from the server at /api/profile when the page loads. However, if I try to do it through ember api method, I get a request for api/profiles. How to make the right query? I need to get the user structure, save it in 'profile' model and use it in routes and components.
2. Suppose the first question dealt with. Next there is a problem with the templates. There is root application template. There is "nav-bar" component, which indicates the name of the authorized user. So, how to put the model of user data in this component? This template is not in a route. Here is {{nav-bar}} template so I need to pass user scheme into it.

   ```
   <div id = "wrapper"> {{nav-bar}} {{outlet}} </div>
   ```

I think maybe i don't get something in architecture of Embers, please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First question. I suppose you tried to do something like this to get your profiles:

```
this.get('store').findAll('profile')
```

By default, Ember will format your HTTP request following the JSON API specification (see http://jsonapi.org/).
JSON API defines that `profile` resources should be accessible at GET `api/profiles`.

Ember allows you to customize the adapter, aka the part that deals with talking to the API. This guide will help you customize the adapter to fit your API : https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Regarding your `nav-bar` component. You can pass variables to component this way :

```
{{nav-bar user=myUser}}
```

Where `myUser` is a variable in your controller calling the component and `user` the name of the variable in the component context.

There is a great library called ember-simple-auth (https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) that will help you to deal with user authentication though. I'd recommend you take a look at it before jumping into it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The problem with {{nav-bar user=myUser}} is that this expression is in aplication.hbs, and this template don't have it's own route, so i can't pass model there.

Comment: You can have a controller and a route for `application`. Just ask ember-cli to do it with `ember generate route application` and `ember generate controller application`. Be aware that all routes are child of the application route. Make sure what you defined there doesn't affect your application too much.